# Using different namespace in same function

Tags: c++, function, oop, namespaces

Why I get error message (error: call of overloaded `myCout()` is ambiguous) when I use two different namespaces in same function making use of `using namespace` directive without fully qualified name space?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace first
{
     void myCout(void)
    {
        cout<<"Hello World is great\n";
    }
}

namespace second
{
     void myCout(void)
    {
        cout<<"Hello Sky is high\n";
    }
}

    int main(void)
    {

        cout<<"Hello World\n";
        using namespace first;
            myCout();

        using namespace second;
            myCout();

        return(0);
    }
```

If I use fully qualified namespaces for `myCout()` in second namespace as given below, there is no issue

```
int main(void)
{
    cout<<"Hello World\n";
    using namespace first;
    myCout();
    second::myCout();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: After you do `using namespace second;`, there are 2 definitions of `myCout`, with the same signature, in the scope of `main`, hence - the call is ambiguous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`using` directives respect scope. So you can introduce a new block scope to limit the availability of the symbols introduced by each:

```
int main(void)
{
    cout<<"Hello World\n";
    {
        using namespace first;
        myCout();
    }

    {
        using namespace second;
        myCout();
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Normally, and so as to avoid conflicts and deep nesting, try to pull in just the identifiers you need with a `using` declaration instead. If for instance you only ever wanted to use class `foo` from `first` then there would be no ambiguity with the following:

```
using first::foo;
using namespace second;
```

Answer (score 3):

`using namespace ...` directives do not create an ordered path; nor do they override all previous ones. So, yes, your code creates an ambiguous situation.

Answer (score 1):

First you use `namespace first`, thus the `myCout` of the first namespace is introduced. Then you use `namespace second`, causing the other `myCout` to be come into play too. The second namespace does *not override* the previous namespace.

As a result, when you call `myCout` for the second time, there are two definitions into play, causing the compiler to rule this as an ambiguous call.

In other words:

```
int main(void)
{
    using namespace first;  // `myCout` of the 1st namespace is introduced
    myCout();

    using namespace second; // `myCout` of the 2nd namespace is introduced
    // and does not override the first namespace!

    myCout();               // Which `myCout`? Of the first or second?

    return 0;
}
```